# regexp - match pattern and prefix before pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need to match a specific pattern

```
(?<!\d|\d )(?:dk)?(\d{2})\D?(\d{2})\D?(\d{2})\D?(\d{2})(?!\d)
```

eg.

```
dk30344510
dk30 34 45 10
30344510
30 34 45 10
```

But I also need to fetch the "prefix" string before the pattern

This is my solution, but it doesn't always work

```
^(.*)(?<!\d|\d )(?:dk)?(\d{2})\D?(\d{2})\D?(\d{2})\D?(\d{2})(?!\d)
```

It's hard to explain so check it here.

https://regex101.com/r/fM1xD3/2

It's too "greedy" and match multiple pattern in the string. The actual match is here a part of the "prefix" of the second match

The example should output two matches. One with `dk30344510` and `62226420`

The example should output `CVR-nr.` as prefix and `dk30344510` as the pattern and second match should be `/ Tlf.` as prefix and `62226420` as the pattern

Comment: You anchor the pattern at the string start, is it true you are only looking for a match at the string start?

Comment: Is this what you want [`(.*?)(?<!\d|\d )((?i:dk)?(?:\d{2}\D?){3}\d{2}(?!\d))`](https://regex101.com/r/zG6yQ4/1) ?

Comment: @revo looks like it.. What have you done? :)

Comment: What is your language / environment?

Comment: the language is php

Comment: Can prefixes like `CVR-nr.` contain digits? Do they end with a period `.`?

Comment: prefixes can contain every letter but no new lines

Comment: and prefixes doesn't have to end with `. ` Could be any letter/char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't output expected results since you have a start of string anchor `^` and a greedy dot `.*`. It means it starts at only start of a string and ends to one successful match only.

**Solution**

Regex:

```
\s*(.*?)\s*\b((?i:dk)?(?:\d{2}\D?){3}\d{2})\b
```

I didn't apply many changes to your main regex. What I did is reducing repeating pattern `\d{2}\D?` and replacing lookarounds with word boundary `\b` token.

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM1xD3/4)**

Comment: `(.*?)` means it is ungreedy and will match any pattern if possible?

Comment: It is un-greedy and consumes characters as less as possible till reaching closer occurrence of next pattern in regex.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one with the optionn 'g' to get multiple resultes

```
^(.*?)\s(dk\d+)\s(.*?)\s(\d+)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM5sL4/1)